# What happens when a function returns a class within a anonymous space?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
class BaseClass {};

namespace { // anonymous
  class SubClass : BaseClass {};
}

BaseClass* somefunc() {
  return new SubClass();
}
```

Since SubClass is in the anonymous namespace, it's not accessible to anything outside the file, but somefunc is not in the anonymous space, therefore accessible. What happens if somefunc return the anonynmous class instance?

Comment: _"What happens if somefunc return the anonynmous class instance?"_ - The same as returning any other type from a function.

Comment: You are returning a pointer not a "class instance"

Comment: @CaptainObvlious what? How is a type equal to an instance?

Comment: It's only the *name* `SubClass` which is not visible to the caller. Everything else about the object is available.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a `BaseClass*`. Anything in a different source file will not be able to cast it to a `SubClass*` since the class won't be accessible. In that case the caller is limited to using the pointer as a `BaseClass` pointer.

Comment: But if you call virtual functions through it, they could invoke the subclass overloads, right?

Comment: @Mamma please explain how it isn't true then.

Comment: @Barmar I don't see why not